# Approximating the normal vector $\mathbf n$ to an "approximated plane".

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization, numerical-methods, physics

Suppose that I have a set of $M$ objects, each with the mass of $m_i$ and at the position $\mathbf 
 r_i$ from the point $\mathbf 0 \in\Bbb R^3$. Assuming also that the center of mass of this group of object is at the origin, i.e.
$$
\sum_i m_i\mathbf r_i = \mathbf 0.
$$

Suppose that this group of objects almost lie in a plane (in some certain sense). I want to find an "approximating normal vector" $\mathbf n \in\Bbb S^1$ to this approximated plane. My idea is that $\mathbf n $ should solve the following constrained minimization problem:
$$\begin{align} &\text{minimize}  &f(\mathbf n) = \sum_i m_i(\mathbf r_i\cdot \mathbf n)^2 \\
&\text{subject to} &g(\mathbf n) = |\mathbf n| = 1.
\end{align}$$
The thought process is that $f(\mathbf n)$ measures the deviation of $\mathbf n$ from being the "true" normal vector to the plane. Of course, if all of our objects actually lie in a plane then the solution to this problem is the unique (up to a change of sign) normal vector to this plane.

> Is there an explicit solution to this constrained minimization problem? Namely, can we write $\mathbf n$ as an algebraic expression of $m_i$'s and $\mathbf r_i$'s?

I tried to solve it using the Lagrange multiplier method but I don't know how to algebraically solve a system of quadratic polynomials in $3$ variables.

The reason for asking the above question is that, for my application, each $\mathbf r_i$ is actually a time-dependent function $\mathbf r_i(t)$ so I can't just solve the problem numerically for every single $t$ because it would take too long. Alternatively, an efficient numerical algorithm that would be suitable for the time-dependent version of this problem would be very welcomed as well (even with different weighting $|\cdot|^p$ instead of $(\cdot)^2$ up there).

Comment: Why that particular form for $f$? You are giving more weight to the points far from origin

Comment: Can you show your attempt at the Lagrange multiplier method? It seems like a mostly linear system to me.

Comment: @Andrei There's no particular reason for that form apart from the fact that I thought it seems plausible to be solved algebraically. The fact that it gives more weight to the points further away is not so worrying according to the people who gave me the problem. In their particular application, all the objects should be at roughly the same distance (or the same order of magnitude at the very least) from the origin.

Comment: @LinAlg wait a second, you're right about that. Let me check what was wrong with the question.

Comment: @LinAlg You're absolutely right. I must have been very tired yesterday when I was solving it before going to bed. This is actually quite an easy problem to solve and I'm feeling stupid now. Thanks a lot for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem as posted is only geometrical so the mass associated to each point is irrelevant. Now given a set of points $p_k,\ k=1,\cdots,n$ and given a plane $\Pi\to (p-p_0)\cdot \vec n = 0$ we have $(p_k-p_0)\cdot \vec n = \delta_k$ as a deviation from the exact inclusion $p_k\in \Pi$ so a good procedure to find such a plane is by solving the minimization problem

$$
\min_{p_0,\vec n}\sum_{k=1}^n\delta_k^2 = \min_{p_0,\vec n}\sum_{k=1}^n\left((p_k-p_0)\cdot \vec n\right)^2 \ \ \text{s. t.}\ \ ||\vec n|| = 1
$$

which is the typical quadratic regression problem.